# Size of modern games

Tags: software-engineering

As a non-game developer, I'm always stunned by the sheer size of modern games. For example, last night I downloaded Killzone for my PS4 and it clocked in at over 30GBs, which to me is absolutely insane, I mean that's several times larger than entire OSes!

Why are modern games so big? Are you guys using like RAW images?

Comment: Art assets such as images, video, and audio use up a ton of space. Exspecialy when only losslessly compressed. Anyways this isn't a question about how to do gamedev and will probably be closed. If you want a dicussion and some insight into exactly where some of those GBs go had on over to the GDSE chat.

Comment: This is just industry trivia; is there a question here you have about a project that you're working on?

Comment: Why is the PC version of Titanfall 48 GB?  [Because the audio is uncompressed to improve performance.](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-03-11-why-the-pc-version-of-titanfall-is-a-48gb-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a huge amount of content in a large scale game. Textures can be large, but are less of a contributor than video and audio.

Depending on audio quality, size can vary quite incredibly. A 4 minute flac encoded song can be 100mb alone. When you reach the level of hours of dialog, even a more lossy format will take up a lot of space.